# What is the importance of $f_k$ in a feistel network being a permutation

Tags: permutation, feistel-network

I was doing some cryptography exercises, one of which was an example of a feistel network. It said that the function $f_k$ was a permutation for all k but didn't explain why that makes a difference. So what is the importance of a function being a permutation in a feistel network?

Answer (score 5):

I assume that you are referring to the round function. This is *false*. The whole advantage of a Feistel network is that $f_k$ does *not* need to be a permutation. Indeed in DES, it is not a permutation. In an substitution-permutation network it needs to be a permutation so that it can be inverted, but in Feistel inversion is possible in any case. Thus, you have more freedom in choosing $f_k$.

Comment: It's not important for $f_k$ to be a permutation in a feistel network. A feistel network is advantageous because you have the freedom to use a function that is *not invertible* since the Feistel network is invertible in any case.

Comment: You have it the opposite. A permutation is invertible. What makes something potentially more secure is having more freedom in choosing the round function. When it does not have to be a permutation there is more freedom.